# Check if 2 databases exist

Tags: vb.net

This is probably a newbie question however how can you check if two datatable are empty? If one datatable has records and the other does not do something. Or if they both have records do something. If none has records do nothing.

```
If dt is nothing andalso dt.rows.count > 0 andalso dt2 is nothing andalso dt2.rows.count > 0 then 

    '  Process

End if
```

Comment: You need to be more precise about your terminology. A database is not a datatable. Anyway what database are you talking about here?

Comment: Sorry auto correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes splitting the code in more simple parts could be a solution to avoid complex if conditions

```
Dim firstEmptyOrNull = dt is Nothing OrElse dt.Rows.Length = 0
Dim secondEmptyOrNull = dt2 is Nothing OrElse dt2.Rows.Length = 0

If firstEmptyOrNull And secondEmptyOrNull Then
  ' Do nothing 
Else if Not firstEmptyOrNull And secondEmptyOrNull Then
  ' Code if the first table is good but not the second one
Else if firstEmptyOrNull And Not secondEmptyOrNull Then
  ' Code if the second table is good but not the first one
Else
  ' Code for both tables good
End If
```